# How to resolve bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android, android-memory

I have designed a custom Image view Gallery, works like a charm on my Samsung Galaxy S3 but when I try to make it work on my HTC Wildfire S, it throws a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget. The code is as follows, any leads?

```
public class ImageViewFlipper extends Activity {

private static final int EXIT = 0;
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private static final String DIRECTORY = "/sdcard/edu";
private static final String DATA_DIRECTORY = "/sdcard/edu";
private static final String DATA_FILE = "/sdcard/imagelist.dat";
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
private Animation slideLeftIn;
private Animation slideLeftOut;
private Animation slideRightIn;
private Animation slideRightOut;
private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
private int currentView = 0;
List<String> ImageList;
private int currentIndex = 0;
private int maxIndex = 0;

FileOutputStream output = null;
OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zero);

    File data_directory = new File(DATA_DIRECTORY);
    if (!data_directory.exists()) {
        if (data_directory.mkdir()) {
            FileUtils savedata = new FileUtils();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ImageViewFlipper.this,
                    "Please wait while we search your SD Card for images...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
            ImageList = FindFiles();
            savedata.saveArray(DATA_FILE, ImageList);

        } else {
            ImageList = FindFiles();
        }

    }
    else {
        File data_file= new File(DATA_FILE);
        if (!data_file.exists()) {
            FileUtils savedata = new FileUtils();


            SystemClock.sleep(100);
            ImageList = FindFiles();
            savedata.saveArray(DATA_FILE, ImageList);
        } else {
            FileUtils readdata = new FileUtils();
            ImageList = readdata.loadArray(DATA_FILE);
        }
    }

    if (ImageList == null) {
        quit();
    }

    SharedPreferences indexPrefs = getSharedPreferences("currentIndex",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (indexPrefs.contains("currentIndex")) {
        currentIndex = indexPrefs.getInt("currentIndex", 0);
    }

    maxIndex = ImageList.size() - 1;

    Log.v("currentIndex", "Index: "+currentIndex);

    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

    slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
    slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    slideRightIn = AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
    slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.slide_right_out);

    viewFlipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in));
    viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out));

    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
            .get(currentIndex)));
    System.gc();

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    int NONE = Menu.NONE;
    menu.add(NONE, EXIT, NONE, "Exit");
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case EXIT:
        quit();
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences indexPrefs = getSharedPreferences("currentIndex",
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor indexEditor = indexPrefs.edit();
    indexEditor.putInt("currentIndex", currentIndex);
    indexEditor.commit();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences indexPrefs = getSharedPreferences("currentIndex", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (indexPrefs.contains("currentIndex")) {
        currentIndex = indexPrefs.getInt("currentIndex", 0);
    }   
}

private List<String> FindFiles() {
    final List<String> tFileList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Resources resources = getResources();
    // array of valid image file extensions
    String[] imageTypes = resources.getStringArray(R.array.image);
    FilenameFilter[] filter = new FilenameFilter[imageTypes.length];

    int i = 0;
    for (final String type : imageTypes) {
        filter[i] = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith("." + type);
            }
        };
        i++;
    }

    FileUtils fileUtils = new FileUtils();
    File[] allMatchingFiles = fileUtils.listFilesAsArray(
            new File(DIRECTORY), filter, -1);
    for (File f : allMatchingFiles) {
        tFileList.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    return tFileList;
}

public class FileUtils {

    public void saveArray(String filename, List<String> output_field) {
         try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(fos);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(gzos);
            out.writeObject(output_field);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             e.getStackTrace(); 
         }
      }

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<String> loadArray(String filename) {
          try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(fis);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(gzis);
            List<String> read_field = (List<String>)in.readObject();
            in.close();
            return read_field;
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              e.getStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
      }

    public File[] listFilesAsArray(File directory, FilenameFilter[] filter,
            int recurse) {
        Collection<File> files = listFiles(directory, filter, recurse);

        File[] arr = new File[files.size()];
        return files.toArray(arr);
    }

    public Collection<File> listFiles(File directory,
            FilenameFilter[] filter, int recurse) {

        Vector<File> files = new Vector<File>();

        File[] entries = directory.listFiles();

        if (entries != null) {
            for (File entry : entries) {
                for (FilenameFilter filefilter : filter) {
                    if (filter == null
                            || filefilter
                                    .accept(directory, entry.getName())) {
                        files.add(entry);
                        Log.v("ImageViewFlipper", "Added: "
                                + entry.getName());
                    }
                }
                if ((recurse <= -1) || (recurse > 0 && entry.isDirectory())) {
                    recurse--;
                    files.addAll(listFiles(entry, filter, recurse));
                    recurse++;
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);

                if (currentIndex == maxIndex) {
                    currentIndex = 0;
                } else {
                    currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
                }
                if (currentView == 0) {
                    currentView = 1;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    System.gc();
                } else if (currentView == 1) {
                    currentView = 2;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.two);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    System.gc();
                } else {
                    currentView = 0;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zero);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                    System.gc();
                }
                Log.v("ImageViewFlipper", "Current View: " + currentView);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                if (currentIndex == 0) {
                    currentIndex = maxIndex;
                } else {
                    currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
                }
                if (currentView == 0) {
                    currentView = 2;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.two);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList.get(currentIndex)));
                } else if (currentView == 2) {
                    currentView = 1;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList.get(currentIndex)));
                } else {
                    currentView = 0;
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zero);
                    iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList
                            .get(currentIndex)));
                }
                Log.v("ImageViewFlipper", "Current View: " + currentView);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void quit() {
    SharedPreferences indexPrefs = getSharedPreferences("currentIndex",MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor indexEditor = indexPrefs.edit();
    indexEditor.putInt("currentIndex", 0);
    indexEditor.commit(); 
    File settings = new File(DATA_FILE);
    settings.delete();
    finish();
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
    System.exit(0);
}


@Override 
public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    try {
      super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    }
  } 
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);




}


 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.gc();
    }
```

}

Edit (Log Cat):

```
     01-05 15:56:38.049: I/Process(573): Sending signal. PID: 573 SIG: 9
     01-05 15:59:38.389: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 64K, 52% free    2613K/5379K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 49ms
      01-05 15:59:48.739: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 9K, 52% free 2634K/5379K, external 3139K/3903K, paused 53ms
      01-05 15:59:49.070: D/szipinf(637): Initializing inflate state
      01-05 16:00:02.489: V/currentIndex(637): Index: 1
      01-05 16:00:02.791: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 57K, 50% free 2748K/5447K, external 5580K/5793K, paused 36ms
      01-05 16:00:03.180: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXPLICIT freed 48K, 51% free 2700K/5447K, external 8692K/10740K, paused 38ms
      01-05 16:00:04.670: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 8K, 50% free 2737K/5447K, external 8692K/10740K, paused 34ms
      01-05 16:00:05.069: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXPLICIT freed 32K, 51% free 2705K/5447K, external 13317K/15365K, paused 54ms
      01-05 16:00:05.069: V/ImageViewFlipper(637): Current View: 1
      01-05 16:00:05.170: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed <1K, 51% free 2705K/5447K, external 14817K/15365K, paused 33ms
       01-05 16:00:19.109: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 5K, 50% free 2734K/5447K, external 14817K/16865K, paused 41ms
      01-05 16:00:19.139: E/dalvikvm-heap(637): 4736340-byte external allocation too large for this process.
       01-05 16:00:19.249: E/GraphicsJNI(637): VM won't let us allocate 4736340 bytes
     01-05 16:00:19.249: D/dalvikvm(637): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 50% free 2734K/5447K, external 14817K/16865K, paused 36ms
     01-05 16:00:19.259: D/skia(637): --- decoder->decode returned false
       01-05 16:00:19.259: D/AndroidRuntime(637): Shutting down VM
      01-05 16:00:19.259: W/dalvikvm(637): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:284)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:309)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:800)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at com.edubridge.ImageViewFlipper$MyGestureDetector.onFling(ImageViewFlipper.java:307)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:568)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at com.edubridge.ImageViewFlipper.onTouchEvent(ImageViewFlipper.java:354)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2099)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
     01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
      01-05 16:00:19.270: E/AndroidRuntime(637):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
      01-05 16:01:27.619: I/Process(637): Sending signal. PID: 637 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/477878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to scale the image down to consume less memory , look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966) answer to see how scale it down the proper way , also when you need to know the width and the height of image without loading it to memory use this code ,

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, bitmapOptions);
int imageWidth = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
int imageHeight = bitmapOptions.outHeight;
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Man Your code led me to hints! I will post the correct answer below in the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (currentView == 0) {
                    currentView = 1;
                    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    //The max size of any dimension (height or width) is 400 px
                    opts.inSampleSize = OG;
                    //Drawable X = Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList.get(currentIndex));
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(ImageList.get(currentIndex), opts);

                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                    System.gc();
                    //ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.one);
                    //iv.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ImageList.get(currentIndex)));
                    //System.gc();
```